# Eclipse: Testing more than one APK at a time

Tags: android, eclipse

I am coding two applications at once using Eclipse.

I wanted to upload both of them to my device for testing. However, when I upload the second one, the first one gets removed..

Any tips on how I can get Eclipse to keep both of the apps on the device at the same time?

Comment: Do you simply want to have them both installed on the device, or debug them in parallel?

Comment: I would like to have them both installed at the same time, not necessarily to debug them in parallel.

Comment: I'm not sure about why eclipse does that, but in your case you can simply install the .apk from the build manually. For instance: `adb install [path/your_app.apk]`.

Comment: @KnutGjærde : make two application version with having different package name. then install it via adb command. you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any tips on how I can get Eclipse to keep both of the apps on the
>   device at the same time?

AFAIK you want to Test two different version of Sample Application in Same Device at a time.

**Solution:** you can not install same application with same version at a same time in any device. However what you can do is to make the Two different Version of your application and install it in your phone. for this you will just have to change the package name of each of version of app. and then you haveto install it via `adb install [path/your_app.apk]` Now you can test your two different version of same application at same time.

Hope it will Help you.

Comment: Thanks, that will do it!
I wanted to test two completely different applications on the same device at the same time. This is possible when running them on the AVD, but when uploading onto a device, Eclipse will only let you have one at a time for some reason...